# How to Search data in tag input and displaying data to table with javascript?

Tags: javascript, ajax, codeigniter

I have an issues for searching and displaying data to table with javascript. i have data with format json but all it can't displayed on table just 1st row, while on console log.data five rows displayed. how to solved this problem. thanks you so much for you guys i hope here this solved.

This is the data:

```
 var  data =[
    {header_id:"TR100001" detail_id:"2" item_code:"SPH001" price:"4000" weight:"2"},
    {header_id:"TR100001" detail_id:"3" item_code:"SPH002" price:"4500" weight:"2"},
    {header_id:"TR100001" detail_id:"4" item_code:"SPH003" price:"30000"weight:"2"},
    {header_id:"TR100001" detail_id:"5" item_code:"SPH004" price:"45000"weight:"2"}];
```

This's View:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="table-responsive">                                        
     <table id="buy_transaction" class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped sticky-header">
                <thead  class="bg-success">
                            <tr>
                            <th width="1">&#9745</th>

                            <th width="5"><b>Detail</b></th>
                            <th><b>Item Code</b></th>                                           

                            <th><b>Price</b></th>

                            <th><b>Weight</b></th>



                            </tr>                                           
                </thead>

            <tbody id="dataTable2">
                 <table id="buy_transaction">
                       <tbody id="dataTable2">
                        <td><input type="checkbox" class="chk" name="chk[]"   value="<?php echo $detail->detail_id; ?>"></td>
                        <td><input type="text" id="detail_id" name="detail_id[]" class="detail_id form-control" value="<?php echo $detail->detail_id ;?>" size="1">                         </td>

                        <td><input type="text"   width="10"  class="item_code form-control" id="item_code" name="item_code[]"   value="<?php echo $detail->item_code; ?>"></td>
                        <td><input type="text"     class="header_id1 form-control" id="header_id" name="header_id[]" value="<?php echo $detail->header_id; ?>" readonly ></td>
                        <td><input type="text"     class="price form-control" id="price"     name="price[]"     value="<?php echo $detail->price; ?>" readonly ></td>

                        <td><input type="text"     class="weight form-control" id="weight"    name="weight[]" placeholder="0"   value="<?php echo $detail->weight; ?>"></td>
                    </table>
           </div>
        </div>
     </div>
```

This's Javascript Code :

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
        function getdHeaderid(header_id){
            var header_id = header_id.val();


            $.ajax({
                    type    : "post",
                    data    : {header_id:header_id},                       
                    url     : "<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/transaction/selltransaction/get_dtHeaderid",
                    dataType:"json",
                    cache :false,
                    success: function(data){ 
                        console.log(data);

                        for(var i=0; i< data.length; i++){
                            var obj=data[i]; 


                            $(".header_id").val(obj.header_id);
                            $(".detail_id").val(obj.detail_id);
                            $(".item_code").val(obj.item_code);
                            $(".price").val(obj.price);
                            $(".weight").val(obj.weight); 


                           }
                         }

            });
        }
     $(document).ready(function() { 
     $('.header_id').on('keyup', function() {
      getdHeaderid($(this)); 

    });
  });

</script>
```

Comment: For starters, your table is missing a `</tbody>`, and you have no `<tr>` elements. Secondly, you are using a class selector inside of a `for` loop, so you will be selecting all of those elements each time through the loop, so the values in those elements will always equal the values for the last iteration of the loop.

Comment: thanks before mhodges for your responses, yes i know that, it just part code. i have problem in javascript. do you know that?

Comment: help me please :)

Comment: Posted an answer, see if my solution helps you

Comment: sorry mhodges i am late, i got error like this:
Uncaught TypeError: tableHTML.push is not a function

Answer (score 0):

Your question wording is pretty hard to understand, but taking my best guess as to what you're looking for - you want a table row for each element from data. If so, here is how you can do that.

```js
var data = [{
    header_id: "TR100001",
    detail_id: "2",
    item_code: "SPH001",
    price: "4000",
    weight: "2"
  },
  {
    header_id: "TR100001",
    detail_id: "3",
    item_code: "SPH002",
    price: "4500",
    weight: "2"
  },
  {
    header_id: "TR100001",
    detail_id: "4",
    item_code: "SPH003",
    price: "30000",
    weight: "2"
  },
  {
    header_id: "TR100001",
    detail_id: "5",
    item_code: "SPH004",
    price: "45000",
    weight: "2"
  }
];

function getdHeaderid(header_id) {
  // make ajax call...
  // ...
  // success callback (data) {
    var tableHTML = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      var obj = data[i];
      var newRow = $(".clone-row").clone(true);
      newRow.removeClass("clone-row");
      newRow.find(".header_id").val(obj.header_id);
      newRow.find(".detail_id").val(obj.detail_id);
      newRow.find(".item_code").val(obj.item_code);
      newRow.find(".price").val(obj.price);
      newRow.find(".weight").val(obj.weight);
      tableHTML.push(newRow);
    }
    $("#dataTable2 tr:not(.clone-row)").remove();
    $("#dataTable2").append(tableHTML);
  // } end success callback
}

getdHeaderid();
```

```css
.clone-row {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="buy_transaction">
  <tbody id="dataTable2">
    <tr class="clone-row">
      <td><input type="checkbox" class="chk" name="chk[]" value="<?php echo $detail->detail_id; ?>"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="detail_id[]" class="detail_id form-control" value="<?php echo $detail->detail_id ;?>" size="1"> </td>

      <td><input type="text" width="10" class="item_code form-control" id="item_code" name="item_code[]" value="<?php echo $detail->item_code; ?>"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="header_id1 form-control" id="header_id" name="header_id[]" value="<?php echo $detail->header_id; ?>" readonly></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="price form-control" id="price" name="price[]" value="<?php echo $detail->price; ?>" readonly></td>

      <td><input type="text" class="weight form-control" id="weight" name="weight[]" placeholder="0" value="<?php echo $detail->weight; ?>"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank a lot mhodges..i think  this solved. i will try this.

Comment: it doesn't work for me , i got error (Uncaught TypeError: tableHTML.push is not a function ) can you help me bro?

Comment: @crazycoder Make sure to include the line "var tableHTML = [];"

Comment: i added a line code like this:
tableHTML.push(newRow);
addRow('dataTable2');

then result 4 rows with same data;

Comment: example: TR100001 | 2 | SPH001 | 4000 | 2 -> it seem 4th times in the table.

Comment: @crazycoder Well, your HTML is problematic. Even when you posted your full HTML, you are missing a `</tbody>` and `</table>`. You also have a table element **and** a table body element with the same ID. While your code will run if you have multiple elements with the same ID, you will get unexpected results and it is *never* recommended. I would recommend that you spend some time going through some basic HTML, CSS, and JavaScript tutorials before trying to load AJAX data, create dynamic HTML, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Your table only has a single row within which you can assign data. Also, you should wrap your table data tags with the `<tr></tr>` tags, to indicate that this is a distinct row in the table. When iterating through your data, you should be creating new rows, for each set of data in your json. Something like this:

```
var table = document.getElementById("buy_transaction");

for(var i = 0; i<data.length; i++) {
    var obj = data[i];
    var row = table.insertRow(i);

    // Insert new cells (<td> elements) at the 1st and 2nd position of the "new" <tr> element:
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    var cell3 = row.insertCell(1);
    var cell4 = row.insertCell(1);
    var cell5 = row.insertCell(1);

    // Add some text to the new cells:
    cell1.innerHTML(obj.header_id);
    cell2.innerHTML(obj.detail_id);
    cell3.innerHTML(obj.item_code);
    cell4.innerHTML(obj.price);
    cell5.innerHTML(obj.weight);
};
```

This way you're for each iteration of the for loop, you're creating a new row for your table and you're inserting the proper values.

Comment: thanks before for your response John Bissonnette, i will be try your solution.

Comment: You're welcome. I think @mhodges answer is more complete, but they both should help set you on the right path to getting this to work.

Comment: yes, i hope your solution can to solved this issue. i am a begginer in javascript.